# T-SQL Group skip and take

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider following tables:

[image: tables]

How to skip and take groups from the table? Tried using Row_Number() but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Used query

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT  Room.Id,  Room.RoomName,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                 (ORDER BY Room.Id) AS RN
         FROM    Room INNER JOIN
                 RoomDetails ON Room.Id = RoomDetails.RoomId)
SELECT  Id, RoomName
FROM    cte 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: "Tried using Row_Number() but it doesn't help" - suggest you post your attempt.

Comment: @MitchWheat: added my attempt code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use partition as part of the dense_rank function

`dense_rank() over (partition by roomid) as row`

see here for some more examples  [Windowing functions](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-advent-2011-day-6)